# Can anyone help identify this stamp please

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Need help to identify this bike please [image]

Comment: Is this a BMX ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a clearer picture.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it looks exactly like a Dyno.

Not the stamp, the bike looks like a Dyno.

Comment: You seem to have created a separate account, probably by mistake.  Please use your original account.